# Find a single object in a collection, HashMap vs List filter

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I generate a list of `Customer` from a file that I read. I store these customers in a `HashMap` where the key is a unique id :

`Map<String, Customer> customers = readCustomers();
//For each object created
customers.put(c.getCustomerId(), c);`

From a second file I get data that I use to update the object in the `HashMap`. I use the key in order to find the object to update:

`//get the details informations
customers.get(customerId).setDetails(details);`

In java 8 I could use :

```
class Customer{
    ... 

    public static Customer find(List<Customer> customers, int id) {
        return customers.stream().filter(c -> c.customerId == id).findAny().get();
    }
}

//usage
List<Customer> customers = readCustomers();    
...
Customer.find(customers, 21).setDetails(details);
```

would there be a performance improvement by using the Java 8 method ? What is the best practice between these methods?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Searching for a value by key in a HashMap takes O(1) expected time, which is faster than the O(n) that searching for the same value in a List would take.

Using Java 8 Streams doesn't change that, since behind the scenes of the fancy new syntax, it still iterates over the elements of the List until finding a match.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know if the fancy new syntax would cause the jvm to be intelligent enough to do the search in any more "clever" manner or would it still just the same looping as if it was in a for loop?

Comment: @David If you use a parallel stream, the search can be executed concurrently on multiple threads, but it still doesn't beat HashMap.

Comment: “takes O(1) expected time” makes no sense as O(1) is not a unit of time while “which is faster than the O(n) ” is simply *wrong*. The correct statement is that a time complexity of O(1) *scales better* than O(n) for “large values of *n*”. However, the conclusion that using the stream API to perform a linear search is no improvement is still correct. Not only because it won’t scale well for large *n*s but also because `.get(customerId)` is much more readable than `.stream().filter(c -> c.customerId == id).findAny().get()`.