# Java: Adding Child List to Parent Main List Iterating

Tags: java, list

We have a Product List, and ProductSubLine Items.
We are taking productSubLineItems and adding them to the appropriate Product List. Is this an optimal way to do it, or any faster/algorithm way?

**Classes:**

```
public class Product {
    private long productId;
    private String productName;
    private BigDecimal costAmount;
    private List<ProductSub> productSublist;
}

public class ProductSub {
    private long productId;
    private long productSubId;
    private String lineItemName;
    private BigDecimal subCost;
}
```

**Method:**

```
List<Product> productList = ..(got from service)
List<ProductSub> productSubList = ..(got from service)

for (Product productItem : productList){
        List<ProductSub> productSubItems = productSubList.stream()
           .filter(x -> x.getProductId() == productItem.getProductId())
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
        productItem.setProductSubList(productSubItems);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution has you looping through the product sublist for each product.  If you collect your list of `ProductSub`s in a map keyed by the id, then you only have to loop through the sublist once and then once through the product list:

Getting an object from a map is constant time complexity so this will be an O(n + m) whereas your solution with filtering and collecting to a list will be O(n * m), where n is the number of products and m is the number of product subs

As an example:

```
    Map<Long, List<ProductSub>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (ProductSub productSub : productSubList) {
      map.computeIfAbsent(productSub.getProductId(), (k) -> new ArrayList<>()).add(productSub);
    }
    for (Product product : productList) {
      product.setProductSubList(map.get(product.getProductId()));
    }
```

Comment: yeah, I thought about that, and the computation time to create the map

Comment: I always thought about it, plus there is a computation time used to create the map,but overall maps are better, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260649/find-a-single-object-in-a-collection-hashmap-vs-list-filter

Comment: I was going to say, assuming you have a large enough set of `Product`s and `ProductSub`s the overhead of creating the map will be negligible compared to the performance gains you will get from using it (as opposed to your original solution)